# Bootstrap Collapse on a Panel, padding causes "jump"

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm applying the collapse behavior to a panel element and it does work but because of the padding applied to `.panel-body`, the animation stops at the padding and then instantly snaps to height. You can see this happening on the most basic example in codepen: http://codepen.io/FiveSixTwo/pen/NRQLPo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="button" data-target="#test" data-toggle="collapse">Test Heading<span class="btn-collapse-header glyphicons glyphicons-chevron-up"></span></div>
    <div id="test" class="panel-body collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
      <p>Laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante fusce
        non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante fusce
        non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante fusce
        non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Semi solution:

```
.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
  p {
    padding: 15px 15px 0;
    &:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 15px; }
  }
}
```

This is a 'semi-solution' because it's not going to work across my entire app without a lot of additional CSS to override the default padding and not break the layout.

Ideally, I want to keep the padding on the `.panel-body` and have the collapse animation play smoothly without a jarring height change at the beginning and end of the animation.

I commented out the solution CSS in my pen so you can see the issue.

I guess the easiest thing to do is to put everything inside another div with padding on it but that's not much better than the semi-solution. I'd prefer a global CSS or even JS solution but so far I haven't come up with anything.

Bootstrap is fine for some things but the more I use it, and the bigger my app gets, the more I hate it.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKeZea

I think it's not working because you're missing the `div.panel-group` that wraps your panel.

Use the Accordion syntax http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante fusce
        non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante fusce
        non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum.</p>
      <p>Laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante fusce
        non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem. As much as I hate having to go back through my entire app and add markup, I suppose that's the only way this is going to work. I'll just add a div with padding since that would be less markup and seems to work well.

Comment: I'm still working on this. Understanding why this is happening would help me figure out a better solution. I'd still prefer a JS solution over adding markup. TIA.

Comment: @sinrise I'm pretty sure that the reason this happened is bootstrap's javascript was expecting a certain DOM structure that you weren't providing.

Comment: Thanks. That much is pretty obvious but it doesn't really get to the root of the problem. I'm trying to figure out why it matters, what the structure is, when the padding is the problem.